# OSX: Creating an automator workflow with Python makes the workflow invalid

Tags: python, macos, file, file-type, automator

I'm making a chat client for OSX, and I wanted it to be able to run as both a .app (for my less technologically inclined users) and as a .py file. I made a workflow app that contained two .py files (an auto-updater and the client itself), run by a python script in the .wflow file. This worked well. However, I couldn't update the updater or workflow script, and the icon was the Python rocket instead of the icon I had chosen. Then, I combined the client .py file with the updater .py file. This still worked, and now I could update the updater. I still couldn't update the python script in the workflow, though, and the icon was still wrong. So, I modified the updater to open the .wflow file, split it into a list (based on python comments in the workflow's python script, such as "#Start") of the stuff before the script, the script's modification time, and the stuff after the script. If the modification time isn't the same as the modification time of the remote file (the one that the updater updates from), then the script downloads the remote .py file, replaces characters (<, >, &) that .wflow files replace ('<' -> "<"), and opens document.wflow with the "w" (write/replace) flag. Then, the stuff that was before the old script, the downloaded script, and the stuff that was after the old script (using file.write(''.join(list))) are all put into document.wflow. This should work, but OSX no longer sees document as an automator file.
[image: Old File]
[image: New File]
[image: Comparison of "Get Info"]
As you can see, OSX thinks that the old file is a Workflow, while the new file is a "Microsoft Excel 97-2004 workbook". The IMClient.app (the application that contains document.wflow) gives this message when I try to run it: "The document "IMClient" could not be opened because it is damaged or incomplete." Does anyone know how to fix this?
I'm using python 2.7 and OSX 10.7. The updater is downloading files via FTP.

If clarification is necessary, just ask. I'll post the working and nonworking files if anyone wants them.

EDIT: the `file` command gives "document.wflow: XML  document text" for both the old and new file.

Comment: What happens if you run `file --mime path/to/document.wflow` and run it again on the new document.wflow?

Comment: Hmm, nvm about that. Thought the type would have been changed resulting in it being opened with different applications. Sorry about that.

Comment: It returns `"document.wflow: application/xml; charset=us-ascii"` for both files.

Comment: @Bair Oh, ok. I'm starting to wonder if the files really are the same, but something about the layout makes it invalid. I don't know.